# Javascript Date Format - Displaying month as xx

Tags: javascript

How can the below code be modified such that the date will appear as: 30/01/2013 as opposed to its current state of: 30/1/2013?

```
var d = new Date();
var xdate = [d.getDate(), d.getMonth()+1, d.getFullYear()].join('/');
```

Comment: There is no built in JavaScript function to return a 2 digit month as far as I know. You would essentially have to say: `if month < 10 return '0'+month`

Comment: Lots of great answers. I guess the simplest way would be to check the month like in many of the examples below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
var d = new Date(),
    m = d.getMonth()+1,
    xdate = [d.getDate(), (m < 10) ? '0' + m : m, d.getFullYear()].join('/');
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a short (left) padding function:

```
function zeroPad(nr,base,chr){
    var  len = (String(base||10).length - String(nr).length)+1;
    return len > 0? new Array(len).join(chr||'0')+nr : nr;
}
//usage
zeroPad(2);          //=> '02'
zeroPad(22);         //=> '22'
zeroPad(22,100);     //=> '022'
zeroPad(22,100,'x'); //=> 'x22'
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to recommend you a mega library [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) it's easy and fast.

```
moment().format("YYYY-MM-DD")
```

result is "2013-01-30"

Answer (score 1):

I use this general-purpose pad function:

```
function pad(input,char,width,onleft) {
    input = ""+input;
    var add = new Array(input.length-width+1).join(char);
    if( onleft) return add+input;
    else return input+add;
}
```

Applied to your code, it would be:

```
var d = new Date();
var xdate = [d.getDate(), pad(d.getMonth()+1,"0",2,true), d.getFullYear()].join("/");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var xdate = [d.getDate(), ('0' + (d.getMonth()+1)).slice(-2), d.getFullYear()].join('/');
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways you could do this by checking if the month is < 10 and then add the 0, I am not a fan of that though, when working with date times in Javascript I find http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/date-time-format this is a great library that handles formatting perfectly